# coredata - deliver / setup default data

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store

I use coreData in my iOS App. It's possible, that the user Add, Delete Data into the Database.
I have to deliver default data ( some different data-sets ).
At the moment, I'm creating the database by first Application launch. I read data from a csv file an create the database with it.
The csv is in the Application sandbox; the coreData (managedDocument) is in ApplicationDocument (creation on runtime...).

It works perfect for me - but I ask me, will Apple allow that, if I push the App to the AppStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach and it can't be a reason for rejection. There is also another way to do it. You can create the database the way you do it now, copy the `.sqlite` file and provide it as your default database. Then copy it on app first run. The following code will do it:

```
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"YourDBName.sqlite"];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourDBName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storeURL.path error:NULL];
        }
    }
```

With this approach you will not need to include your `csv` file in your bundle.

Comment: I thought about that solution; with some @#ifdef DEBUG@ remove the code in release for creation and use the sqlite the way you described.

Comment: You will also need to remember to uncheck the `csv` form your target before archiving your app as you will not need it anymore.

Comment: what did you mean with uncheck? If I provide the sqlite file I have to remove the csv? yes, of course

Comment: No need to remove, just select the file in Xcode and uncheck the checkbox in `Target Membership` tab. Then do Product->Clean. Xcode will skip the file on the next build.

Comment: Ok.
And the other way; maybe i will use the csv to create the database on first launch; it's not common to delete the files after creation? I dislike that, because in case, that the database is corrupted I'm able to create the database.

Comment: You can't delete any file included in the bundle. So the default DB will stay there forever. If you want to recreate the database used with Core Data, just delete it and copy the default one again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apple does allow shipping a database populated by default.
the standard way to do it is to ship a default database in your bundle, then at launch time check if there is a database in your application documents directory, and if it does not exist, then copy the database from your bundle to the documents directory.