# Adding preloaded .sqlite data base to XCode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Sorry for maybe dumb question, but I am trying to understand how Core Data works. I have little .sqlite data base for test, preloaded simply with strings. I have sample project for learning Core Data for beginners and it works fine with it's internal .sqlite data base, and data base structurally the same as mine. I want to replace it with my data base for test, but I really can't find existing data base file in Xcode Navigator window and how can it linked to .xcdatamodeld of the project. Do I understand right that I need to add my data base to project and then link it somehow to .xcdatamodeld, and if not, where it stored in the project and how can I switch to using my data base instead of sample data base?

Thanks a lot of any advance!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11923036/730701).

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I tried, but now I have "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model". Why NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has now become nil? Also I tried to change fileManager to [NSFileManager defaultManager] to retrieve a file

Comment: It's really hard to tell. There is something wrong with your Core Data setup. If you have a line like this one in your app delegate: `__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];` you need to make sure that your managed object model is not nil. Check if your model file exists and it's added to target.