# Use existing data in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm pretty new to iOS development and definitely do not completely understand the workings of `Xcode` and stuff. I am creating an iOS application and have been using `Sqlite` to store data on the device. I had added a `sqlite3` database to the project but I noticed that in the simulator the database does not exist at first run of the application and thus has to be created in code. This was ok until now. I am supposed to have a list with dates that should come with the application. Is it possible to have the application use a database with some data already in it at first run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [coredata - deliver / setup default data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922800/coredata-deliver-setup-default-data) - Even if that question was for Core Data, the answer applies to a default sqlite file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookdb.sql"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
        return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookdb.sql"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

This is to copy over the sqlite database if it does not exist..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. I had already put together some code but for some reason it would not work. The only difference was that in my code I used pathForResource on the mainbundle to find my database file and it seemed to return the correct path but when copying I received a cocoa error 4 (which doesn't say very much).

Comment: put in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of appdelegate.

Comment: I did put my code there, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the sqlite file is inside your bundle.

You need to move it to the library folder (or Documents folder) after applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Checkout NSFileManager for more info...

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try this. So it is not necessary to use CoreData?

Comment: CoreData is based on sqlite3 underneath anyway. Most of the times the file should be moved or created to the library folder.