# iOS 7 - Use a pre existing SQLite 3 Database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am relatively new to iOS Development. I want to use a pre populated sqlite3 database for the application I am making. I have looked around the Internet and found [this site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) and it gave a good example. However, I am using a database table with around 120 columns and 27000 rows and that isn't an option for me.

So, my main question is, is there a simple way to use/import a pre populated SQLite3 Database (or a CSV Table) to your application? Similar to how importing a SQLite3 Database in Android works. If so, how?

Follow up question:

Is it possible for an iOS application to download and execute an SQLite3 Database for use? I did a quick look in the Internet and it didn't give me anything helpful.

I'm sorry if this is a rather simple topic and I'm missing out on something basic/easy.

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **YES** You can do both

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418885/use-existing-data-in-ios-application) may help you.